# error: too many arguments for class template in a parameter packed class template

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

I created a primary template and two specializations: one is for a void-type, the other is a parameter pack for different parameter types.

The background is a "connection"-engine, to connect member functions returning void, so I don't need the return type, just the parameter type.
The classes are just like wrappers, providing a syntax-friendly static function which creates the concrete Link.

so my code looks like this:

```
  /**
   * CalleeCreator class, primary template
   */
  template <typename T> class CalleeCreator;

  template <typename... TParams>
  class CalleeCreator<TParams...> final
  {
    public:
      template <typename TObject, void(TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
      constexpr static void create(const char*name, TObject& instance)
      {
        new Callee< void (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function>( name, instance);
      }
  };

  template <>
  class CalleeCreator<void> final
  {
      template <typename TObject, void(TObject::*Function)(void)>
      constexpr static void create(const char* name, TObject& instance)
      {
        new Callee< void (TObject::*)(void), Function>( name, instance);
      }
  };
```

as soon as I call something like this:

```
CalleeCreator<uint8_t, uint16_t>::create<Object,
    &Object::method> ("test", *this);
```

I get that compilation error: error: **too many arguments for class template**.

While calling

```
CalleeCreator<void>::create<Object,
    &Object::method> ("test", *this);
```

works as expected

What I don't understand is, that I created another version with a return type and the same primary template:

```
  template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams>
  class CalleeCreator<TReturn(TParams...)> final
  {
    public:
      template <typename TObject, TReturn(TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
      constexpr static void create(ConstCharPtr name, TObject& instance)
      {
          new Callee< TReturn (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function>( name, instance);
      }
  };

  template <typename TReturn>
  class CalleeCreator<TReturn(void)> final
  {
    public:
      template <typename TObject, TReturn(TObject::*Function)(void)>
      constexpr static void create(ConstCharPtr name, TObject& instance)
      {
          new Callee< TReturn (TObject::*)(void), Function>( name, instance);
      }
  };
```

if I call them, everything is fine and working:

```
CalleeCreator<void(uint8_t, uint16_t)>::create<Object,
        &Object::method> ("test", *this);
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong here.

Additionally, the Callee class to see the templates and the constructor.

```
/** Class Callee, primary
 */
template <typename T, T> class Callee;


template <typename TObject, typename... TParams,
          void (TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
class Callee<void (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function> final
{
  public:
    Callee(const char* name, TObject& instance){}
};
```

of course there is a Callee-class with a return type for the other solution as well.

Comment: `TReturn(TParams...)` is a single type. `void` is a single type. `TParams...` is a list of types.

Comment: @ecatmur does this mean there is no solution? because a list of types can't be a primary template. 
As I see it's not possible to use it the same way or I need a nother name for the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a primary variadic class template:

```
template <typename... TParams>
class CalleeCreator final
{
    // ...
};
```

You don't need to a partial specialization, and you don't need to specialize for `R(void)` - that's an archaism (from C), the way to write a function type taking 0 parameters in C++ is with empty parentheses.

Comment: This solved the problem. simple as this. 
The trick is to not create a "prototyped" primary template, but to define the CalleeCreator as you did as first in the used file. Thank you!